# JavaScript Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an array such as: `[{word: 1}, {word2: 1}, {word3, 5}]`

```
for (var item in text) {
  var word = text[item];
  var key = {};
  key[word] = 1;
  array.push(key);
}

for (var wrd in array ) {
  console.log('Word ' + Object.keys(array[wrd]));
  console.log('Number ' + array[wrd]);
}
```

The keys print ok, however the number still prints as `[object Object]`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Similar answers don't seem to work.

Comment: Note that `for..in` is for looping objects, not arrays.

Comment: @elclanrs Don't you mean it is for looping arrays and not objects?

Comment: Whenever you append an object to a string, it converts that object to a string which you see as `[object Object]`. Just do `console.log(array[wrd])` and you'll see the object you desire. Also, as @elclanrs mentioned, you should only use `for..in` loops for going over the keys of an object. For arrays, use [`for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or one of the built-in array functions such as [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: You can use a for...in for arrays. It simply loops through the keys of the array. You can then use that key to get the array item... `for (var key in array) { console.log(array[key]); }`. Probably better to loop through with an iterative integer to begin with, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in the items themselves and not the positions, you should use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) rather than `for..in`. You probably want something like this:

```
array.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log('Word ' + Object.keys(item));
    console.log('Number ' + item[Object.keys(item)]);
});
```

Note that this will only work if each item has exactly one key. Otherwise, you will need to iterate over the keys for each item as well.

P.S. The reason your code prints `"[object Object]"` is because `array[wrd]` is one of the items of your array (e.g., `{word: 1}`) and when you append that to a string (`'Number ' + array[wrd]`) it represents the object itself as the string `'[object Object]'`.

P.P.S. (Based on the edit to the original question):

If you're trying to construct `array` to look like `[{word: 1}, {word2: 1}, {word3, 5}]`, then it depends on what you're starting with. I assume that `text` is an array of words and you're trying to construct an array of word/word-count pairs. If that's the case, then I suggest you construct an object that maps words as keys to counts, as in the following:

```
var text = ['word', 'word2', 'word3', ...];
var frequencyMap = {};
text.forEach(function(word) {
    var count = frequencyMap[word] || 0; // retrieve last count (if any)
    frequencyMap[word] = count + 1;
});
```

If you really need an array of word/count objects, you can convert the map to one with:

```
var array = [];
Object.keys(frequencyMap).forEach(function(word) {
    array.push({word : frequencyMap[word]});
})
```

Comment: This does not address OPs question. They're wondering why `array[wrd]` is printed as `"[object Object]"`. As I already stated, it's from concatenating an object with a string. Furthermore, passing an array of keys as a key to an object will just produce `undefined` in most cases.

Comment: @MikeC - OP did not ask why it printed as `"[object Object]"`. The question was "Is there a better way of doing this?"

Comment: OP: "The keys print ok, however the number still prints as [object Object]/". That's the problem. That's why they're asking for a better way.

Comment: @MikeC - And I provided a better way, which directly addressed OP's problem.

Comment: No you didn't. [Here's your code added to OPs.](https://jsfiddle.net/0xh0d7k1/1/) It's still being printed incorrectly (on the first line) and even if they were asking for a better way of approaching the problem in general, that seems rather opinion based. I can think of an approach that provides the same result but is, in my opinion, better than yours.

Comment: @MikeC - Ah. I see the problem. The array object that you are constructing in your fiddle is not at all like the array in the first line of OP's post. If you start with such an array (which I assume was what OP's setup code produces), then my code works just fine.

Comment: It's exactly like what OP posted. I literally just copied OPs code, added in a `var` statement for the array and removed `etc.` to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: @MikeC - Just before the call to `forEach` in your fiddle, examine the value of `array`. You'll find that it's not at all like what OP indicates `array` should be. You assumed that the first line should be the value of `text` but I assumed that the first line should be the value of `array` and it was being constructed from some other array (not shown) called `text`.

Comment: I could see why you might think that. With that being the case, OP needs to better define the dataset before a definitive answer could be found. I still stand by my opinion that a "better way" is opinion-based and such answers should be closed.

Comment: @MikeC - In view of OP's edit, it would seem that my assumption about OP's intent was correct.